# How to view outline with slide counts in org-beamer-mode?

Tags: org-mode, beamer

While working on a presentation in `org-beamer-mode` today I accidentally hit some unintended sequence of keys. This produced an outline view of the presentation, where each item in the outline had numbers in parenthesis that appeared to represent the number of slides under that heading. I tried `view-lossage` as soon as I realized what I had done, but still could not figure it out.

What did I do?